# disable java log rotation

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I use java.util.logging.Logger to log in my app :

```
    FileHandler fh=new FileHandler(this.todayFileName, 0, 1, true);

    fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());

    Logger.getLogger(rootLogger.getName()).setLevel(Level.ALL);

    Logger.getLogger(rootLogger.getName()).addHandler(fh);
```

but this does work well except that log rotation is enabled.

and i get files :

run.log run.log.1 run.log.2

what I want is to get only one log file, with no rotation enabled.

how do I do that ?

Comment: Mandatory answer: don't use java.util.logging, it's awful. Use something else. Anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the same application more than once at the same time, java.util.logging will create many log file like run.log run.log.1 run.log.2

And are you sure that your application close correctly, because I already got this problem. Since my application didn't close correctly, when I started my application, that created a myApplication.log.1

Answer (score 1):

You must use the FileHandle constructor tht uses a file name and a boolean or the one that uses the file name only, in this way you are going to get a single log file with no rotation.

Regards,
Luis.

Comment: This works for me. E.g: `Handler fh = new FileHandler("output.log",1048576,1,true);`. Only one file is created, it is appended and is cleared out every 1048576 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the answers already given I would question your desire to disable logrotation. There are very good reasons to have logs rotate (like running out of disc space and so on) that make is a standard procedure. I would say investigate what makes you want to turn it off and eliminate that need. E.g. if you want to be able to mine the logs information easily maybe you should consider looking at a package that does that for you (e.g. splunk or whatever) and can work fine with rotated logs. Also consider that log rotation is highly configurable so maybe you just want to change the rotation config. Also consider that you could get the information you need from the log sent somewhere else for that purpose and leave the rotating log alone...

And depending on the operating system/log rotation configuration system you will probably be able to just turn the rotation off right there in the operating system and not worry about your code.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  My problem with this is, mine is a high traffic web service application and logging using this creates a lot of file in the name of log.1,log.2 etc., which the client feels is not good.  So I looked for options to disable this.  Also I already set the webservice to create 1 log file per day by adding the current date with the name of the log file.

Comment: You know how to disable it in operating system(Red Hat Linux)?

Comment: As usual the man page should help. E.g. http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html and what about the client feeling this is not good. What do they know about unix system administration? What is their suggestions? Log rotation is a well known and working setup and procedure/configuration. Do they actually understanding what it does?

Answer (score -1):

If you must use this, then try Integer.MAX_INT instead of 0. The 0 might actually be treated as 0 bytes, and thus cause a rotation every time you initialise it.

BTW if you want 'only one file, no rotation' then use the 1-arg constructor that just takes the file name, and it will do the right thing.

Comment: From the FileHandler javadoc: "limit specifies an approximate maximum amount to write (in bytes) to any one file. If this is zero, then there is no limit."  So setting to 0 should disable the limit, not cause infinite rotation.